# Is the Geometry(4326) an alias for Geography datatype?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, wgs84, geography-data-type

The main reference about Geography datatype seems [docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography):

> Prior to PostGIS 2.2, the geography type only supported WGS 84 long lat (SRID:4326). For PostGIS 2.2 and above, any long/lat based spatial reference system defined in the spatial_ref_sys table can be used (...)
> Regardless which spatial reference system you use, the units returned by the measurement (...)  are in meters.

But it is not explicit: when I am "casting to another type" and when PostGIS is using internally the same "Geography calculations", **without any casting need**?

Other texts, like [postgis-intro/geography](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html), and other documents are also confuse: ... is a *Geometry* with no projection a *Geography*? 
The "standard no projection" is `Geometry(4326)`, so, **why the need for a *Geography* data type** if PostGIS can detect it by SRID?

Of course, for PostgreSQL is important to change the data type, to do *function overloading*... But the guide not explains the equivalence schemas in the internal representation.

---

### NOTES

There are some previous answers to earlier questions:

- [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/283509/7505) to [Oracle equivalent to postgis EPSG 4326 "geometry" type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283242), and
- [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/97926/7505) to [Understanding geography, geometry, distance and wkt in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97922)

but those questions are not duplicates of this one.

About comments, to avoid terminological confusion: a *Geometry* with `SRID=4326` is not "only lat long". The so-called "WGS84" **is a** [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) (coordinate reference system), a synonym  and human-readable abbreviation for [`urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326`](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/gml/). Any formal **standard CRS** is **composed by**   ellipsoid parametrized model reference + parametrized datum reference, so, the formal definition is:

- the WGS84's [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid)  is `urn:ogc:def:ellipsoid:EPSG::7030`;
- the WGS84's  [datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum#Horizontal_datum) is `urn:ogc:def:datum:EPSG::6326`.

Comment: EPSG:4326 is lat long

Comment: Hi @nmtoken, can you post a link or links to official `EPSG:7030` documentation? The only thing that I see at Spatialreference is [this citation as Autority](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32614/html/)... And explain why you say that [`4326`](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/) **"is not"** the standard Geography-datatype reference. (again [there 7030 is an authority code](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/prettywkt/))

Comment: For official should look at the `EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry`  GML representation for EPSG:7030  is:  http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:ellipsoid:EPSG::7030

Comment: @nmtoken, seems you wrong. It is confuse, but seems that WGS84 **is** [`urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326`](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/gml/), a CRS (coordinate reference system). In this link we can see its composition: `urn:ogc:def:ellipsoid:EPSG::7030` (**an ellipsoid model** definition) and `urn:ogc:def:datum:EPSG::6326`, the current datum of WGS84.

Comment: Epsg 4326 is the CRS, I was commenting on the code for the ellipsoid. See WGS84 tag description

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**tl;dr**: No. But see the update at the end.

---

`GEOMETRY` and `GEOGRAPHY` are different PostgreSQL `TYPES`; exposed as higher level (*SQL*), [user-defined](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xtypes.html) *composite types* to the *psql* environment, but implemented as lower level (*C*) *base types*.

These *base types* are defined on the *C* level with e.g. their own typemod constraints, TOAST support, data I/O functions, operator classes and casting behaviour. On top of that, both types have their own indexing mechanics.

On the *SQL* level, both types (optionally) accept a `TEXT` and a `NUMERIC` parameter, which translate to *geometry type*, and *spatial reference*. Additionally, you can index both with the same command (`USING GIST(<geom>)`), although internally those indexes differ, and `CAST` between them almost seamlessly, with some caveats as seen in the example below.

- **In every way, these are different types with fundamentally different mechanics, despite their deliberately similar handling.**

---

Under the hood, the core difference is the mathematical representation and calculation of and with the given coordinates, in two words: **planar** vs. **spheroidal**.

The `GEOMETRY` type is bound by definition to a 2D planar reference, and operates with *Cartesian math* **regardless of the nature of the CRS**; distance between two points is a straight line as e.g. per *Pythagoras*, **even if your geometries are defined in a geodetic reference** (e.g. *EPSG:4326*). The `GEOMETRY` type is meant to work best for **projected CRS**.

The `GEOGRAPHY` type is inherently assuming that the given coordinates are **geodetic coordinates**, thus operating solely on great circle math (spherical) and/or it's more complicated application on spheroidal/ellipsoidal bodies. The `GEOGRAPHY` type is meant to work with **geographic/geodetic RS (*Longitudes/Latitudes*) only**.

- **Neither does PostGIS "*the same 'Geography calculations'"*, nor detects the nature of a given SRS to do so.**

---

The WGS84 ellipsoid (*EPSG:7030*) is allegedly among the most usable representation of our planet on a global scale, and is widely supported in transformations to and from projections and other ellipsoids. Also, it is and has ever since been the base reference of most of our positioning systems.

It is *de facto* a global standard for spatial data storage and its interchangeability.

- **In PostGIS, the actual default SRS is *no SRS*, or `0`** (which is bad to have...).

---

Now, as a small example of what PostGIS does with wrong SRS definitions; you can do this (note that the coordinates *should* represent *degrees*...)

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID('POINT(1000 1000)'::GEOMETRY, 4326));
```

returning a valid `GEOMETRY`

```
st_astext       |
----------------|
POINT(1000 1000)|
```

while this

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID('POINT(1000 1000)'::GEOGRAPHY, 4326));
```

returns a valid `GEOGRAPHY`

```
st_astext     |
--------------|
POINT(-80 -80)|
```

along with the note

```
Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
```

Btw. coercing here means sth. like

- Lat: `-90 + (1000 % 90) = -80`
- Lon: `-180 + (1000 % 180) = -80`

so it effectively walks around the globe until 1000 degrees are traversed.

**Yet** the `GEOGRAPHY` type does not care if you do

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID('POINT(1000 1000)'::GEOGRAPHY, 3857));
```

except for the above note of coordinate range coercion, while it actually *should* (if it could; we're assigning a SRS on the created type, so it would be the function assigning it that needed to) inform you about the nature of the SRS (and, since we're at it, IMHO also the uselessness of EPSG:3857...).

**However**, a `CAST` to `GEOGRAPHY` will indeed check the SRS and denies the cast for non-geodetic SRS, e.g.

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID('POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY, 3857)::GEOGRAPHY;
```

will error out with

```
ERROR: Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
```

- **In no way does PostGIS any fail-saving for you in these matters, except when using a `CAST` to `GEOGRAPHY`.**

---

**Update as per comment request:**

Because PostGIS defines the cast **from** `GEOMETRY` **to** `GEOGRAPHY` (and only this way) `AS IMPLICIT`, PostgreSQL is free to cast any `GEOMETRY` to `GEOGRAPHY` whenever it is necessary, or possible, to solve ambuiguity. This affects parameters to functions in the following ways, where PostgreSQL will `CAST` implicitly:

- if a distinct signature is unambiguously invoked that accepts only `GEOGRAPHY` types; an example would be the `ST_Area` signatures where, when explicitly used with a value for `use_spheroid`, PG casts a `GEOMETRY` to `GEOGRAPHY`
- an ambiguous signature for both types is used (i.e. a type overloaded function), and only one parameter is passed in as `GEOGRAPHY`, the other will get cast; an example is `ST_DWithin` where, when one parameter gets passed as `GEOMETRY` and the other as `GEOGRAPHY`, the former will get cast to `GEOGRAPHY`

One might say, since only the `CAST` **to** `GEOGRAPHY` is `IMPLICIT`, it has inherent precedence.

In these cases, since the `CAST` is used, PostGIS *will* inform you (and deny the execution) if the `GEOMETRY` in question does not use a geodetic SRS!

- **The secret ingredient to ambiguity is an implicit `CAST`**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the good explanations (!). Can you add some comments about ambiguous assertions on the guide? Example 1. about ambiguous functions like [*float ST_Area(geography geog, boolean use_spheroid=true)*](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html), that say that you can use 2 parameters only with *Geography*, but we  can use with *Geometry(4326)*, and the behaviour will be the same as Geography, doing supposed same calculus. Example 2. about "Geography vs Geometry" **distinct** internal libraries, and when PostGIS is mixing calls to both in the same Geometry-parameter function.

Comment: @PeterKrauss see the update - hope it helps clarifying your comment?

Comment: The WGS 84 ellipsoid is not EPSG:4326 the ellipsoid is EPSG:7030

Comment: @mmtoken thx., corrected.

Comment: To avoid terminological confusion: the named "WGS84" **is a** CRS (coordinate reference system), so synonyms and human-readable abbreviation for [`urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326`](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/gml/). Any formal **standard CRS** is **composed by**   ellipsoid parametrized model reference + datum reference. The WGS84's ellipsoid  is `EPSG:7030` and the WGS84's  datum is `EPSG::6326`.