# Geometry vs geography vs spheroid for polygon-contains-point (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, topology

Many operations behave differently in `geometry` vs `geography`, e.g. the distance between two points.

But what if I only need to check whether a polygon contains a point?

- Does that operation differ between `geometry` vs `geography`?
- Does that operation differ between `use_spheroid` being `false` vs `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean function ST_Contains https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html or ST_Within https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html by the documentation they do not have a switch for `use_spheroid` and they can be used only with geometries, not with geographies. If you mean something else, please explain.

The question is relevant and the following query returns "false" even the point would be inside the polygon if they were geographies.

```
select
ST_Contains(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT ( -0.847 24.615 )'),
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 26.314 -32.134, -26.556 -9.337, 24.373 53.233, 69.24 16.855, 26.314 -32.134 ))'));
```

[image]

Comment: I'm new to PostGIS and was surprised that ST_Contains didn't support geographies, but I figure ST_Intersects or ST_Within would do what I need.

(You're correct that neither of them support use_spheroid.  I saw use_spheroid on other functions and was just wondering whether the math worked out.)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, and the issue is where the plane is bound to fail to represent the sphere.

---

As an overview of both types:

- [Is the Geometry(4326) an alias for Geography datatype?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367366/is-the-geometry4326-an-alias-for-geography-datatype/367374#367374)

As an example:

```
WITH
    ply(wkt) AS (
        VALUES ('SRID=4326;POLYGON((-45 0, 0 90, 45 0, -45 0))')
    ),
    pt(wkt) AS (
        VALUES ('SRID=4326;POINT(-45 45)')
    )
SELECT ST_Intersects(ply.wkt::GEOMETRY, pt.wkt::GEOMETRY) AS "with GEOMETRY(4326)",
       ST_Intersects(ply.wkt::GEOGRAPHY, pt.wkt::GEOGRAPHY) AS "with GEOGRAPHY(4326)"
FROM   ply, pt
;


 with GEOMETRY | with GEOGRAPHY 
---------------+----------------
 f             | t
```

We  know that, **on a sphere** the `POINT(-45 45)` does, in fact, **lie on the edge** of the triangle defined by `POLYGON((-45 0, 0 90, 45 0, -45 0))` - and **the `GEOGRAPHY` data type is aware of that**, too!

This, however, is **what the `GEOMETRY` data type assumes**:

[image]

where

- the **red dot** is `POINT(-45 45)`
- the **red line** is `LINESTRING(-45 0, -45 90)`
- the **red *dashed* line** is `LINESTRING(-45 0, 0 90)`

Note that the two lines end in seemingly different end points, and the `GEOMETRY` type **does take the different coordinates into acocunt**; but of course, any point with `latitude = 90°` is **the same point on a sphere**!

Thus, *on a sphere*, the *red line* and the *red* dashed *line* **are equal**, and the `POINT(-45 45)` an element **in both**! But treated *as planar coordinates*, **spherical equality is destroyed**!

---

Some considerations:

- the perceived magnitude of this effect is scale dependent: the smaller the scale, the larger the perceived impact
- there are projection types that try to overcome this issue on a larger, regional scale
- in theory, this effect *may* have a different impact when used with a spheroid (i.e. a geoid)
- except for `ST_Intersects`, **no spatial relationship function in PostGIS supports the `GEOGRAPHY` type**; `ST_Intersects` uses a sphere as reference