# Incorrect ST_Area after changing to 4326 in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, area, geometry-conversion

I'm trying to change the geometry in our database from 3857 to 4326 so that I can use more functionality within PostGIS. It converts them all properly when I run the alter column and transform query:

```
ALTER TABLE title_polys
 ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326) USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,3857),4326);
```

However, when I run `ST_Area`, the results are way off unless I use `ST_Area(geom,false)`. It works all OK if I change the geometry column to a geography, but I'd rather not as I'd lose functionality and performance based on what we need.

Is this a bug with PostGIS or am I missing something?

```
select st_area(geom) AS exact, st_area(geom, false) AS estimate from title_polys
```

| exact | estimate |
| --- | --- |
| 2.490170562234932e-07 | 1895.9551152943063 |
| 4.157266523887839e-09 | 75.72500465242514 |
| 1.1955232197819434e-07 | 971.9694598590975 |
| 8.793502212797464e-09 | 67.6315680685311 |
| 7.044158502581973e-08 | 532.1479617588419 |

[image]

Comment: Please use a local CRS for area calculation. The 4326 is not metric

Comment: 3857 (Web Mercator) cannot measure area correctly, so you should not use that a a reference value. `geometry` area is calculated as a Cartesian value, and Cartesian degrees are useless. You simply need to *cast* the `geometry` to `geography` to get the correct value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL is free to implicitly `CAST(GEOMETRY AS GEOGRAPHY)` in cases where a function signature can thus be honored unambiguously - as with

> `ST_Area(geography geog, boolean use_spheroid=true)`.

and calculations are made on the spheroid/ellipsoid.

Using the single parameter signature

> `ST_Area(geometry g1)`

will calculate metrics in the cartesian plane, using **CRS units** (here *degrees*).

**Related:**

- [Is the Geometry(4326) an alias for Geography datatype?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367366/is-the-geometry4326-an-alias-for-geography-datatype/367374#367374)

---

You can either

- **explicitly** cast to `GEOGRAPHY`:

  ```
  SELECT ST_Area(geom::GEOGRAPHY) [...];
  ```
- **explicitly** set the `use_spheroid` parameter:

  ```
  SELECT ST_Area(geom, TRUE|FALSE) [...];
  ```

to trigger the respective signature.

Comment: Nice, but that that automatic cast to geography does not seem to be documented in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html. Is it documented in some other place?

Comment: @user30184 no, not directly. This is a PostgreSQL feature and is defined in the type cast implementation - see my (now) linked answer - the actual `CAST` implementation is [here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/c8eedf3aeb1dd571ef7bcf15ad0c19486d9dd031/postgis/geography.sql.in#L193). Note that the [reverse](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/c8eedf3aeb1dd571ef7bcf15ad0c19486d9dd031/postgis/geography.sql.in#L202) is *not* `IMPLICIT`.