# PostGIS query with ST_Intersects/ST_Contains is incredibly slow

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-query, st-intersects

I want to run a PostGIS query that selects roads (total dataset: 103 mio.) that are inside a buffer polygon. The subqueries as standalone are very fast, but when I add the `ST_Contains` or similar operations (`ST_Intersects` etc.) the query is incredibly slow, it takes 1 hour or more to complete.

```sql
SELECT ST_AsGeoJson(ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(shape), 4326))
FROM   roadstable
WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_BUFFER(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(8.2409755 48.7626881 ,8.7230855 48.5520615)', 4326)::geography, 500), ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(shape), 4326))
```

I already tried to speed the query up by setting a spatial index, doing subqueries and subdividing the geometries but without success.

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_roads on roadstable USING gist(shape); 

WITH roads AS (
    SELECT ST_SUBDIVIDE(ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(shape), 4326))::geometry AS roadgeom FROM roadstable),
buffer AS (
    SELECT ST_SUBDIVIDE(ST_BUFFER(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(8.2409755 48.7626881 ,8.7230855 48.5520615)', 4326)::geography, 500)::geometry) AS buffergeom)
SELECT ST_AsGeoJson(roads.roadgeom), buffer.buffergeom
WHERE  ST_Intersets(buffer.buffergeom, roads.roadgeom);
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Why is this query so slow? Are there other possibilities to improve performance?

Comment: Please add the output of the explain of your query. Also dwithin will be faster than a buffer

Answer (score 7):

The query uses
`where ST_Intersects(ST_BUFFER(..),ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(shape), 4326))`

and the index uses `CREATE INDEX idx_roads on roadstable USING gist(shape);`

The index will not be used, as you are not querying `shape` but a transformation of it.

Here, the index would have to be

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_roads ON roadstable 
 USING gist(ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(shape), 4326));
```

**BUT**, honestly, this query and index are awful. Why not fixing your data so that the geometry is stored with the proper axis order and crs?!?

```sql
ALTER TABLE roadstable
  ALTER COLUMN shape 
   TYPE GEOMETRY(LINESTRING,4326) 
  USING (ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(shape), 4326));
```

And then you can create the index on `shape` as you did.

PS: regarding subdividing the shapes: there is no need to subdivide the buffer, as it already has a fairly limited number of vertices and the circular shape is not too different than its bounding box. It *may* be useful to subdivide the roads if there are very long and/or oddly shaped and fairly dense, but don't do this until you have fixed the shape or index

Answer (score 5):

**First off:**

If you really need a call to `ST_FlipCoordinates`, you are bound to plenty of trouble going forward, with basically every query you make - especially if working with the `GEOGRAPHY` type and its coordinate bounds (see the respective parts of [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367374/93656)).

**I strongly suggest you re-create the table with the correct ordinate order**, but I will assume the call in my answer.

---

An index is built on top of the *expression* that is specified during index creation; that *expression* can be a variety of statements, most prominently a *column reference* to the target table. A query can only ever benefit from index lookups if a possible invocation uses **this exact *expression* used during index creation**.

Your query has a possible invocation hook in the `WHERE` filter via `ST_Intersects` - however, you are passing a **new type of `GEOGRAPHY`** (via casting the result of `ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates)`) to the function, which is **not covered by the `GIST` index on `shape`** (neither is the `GEOGRAPHY` type, nor would be the uncast `GEOMETRY` result from the two functions!)

In addition, it is **one of the most infamous anti-patterns** in the PostGIS(/GEOS/JTS) environment to use an `ST_Buffer` for *proximity* searches - an intersection test is up to several orders of magnitude slower than an optimized proximity check with `ST_DWithin`.

---

With all that in mind, running

```
SELECT
  ST_AsGeoJson(ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(r.shape), 4326))
FROM
  roadstable AS r
WHERE
  ST_DWithin(
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(8.2409755 48.7626881, 8.7230855 48.5520615)', 4326)::GEOGRAPHY,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(r.shape), 4326)::GEOGRAPHY,
    500
  )
;
```

with a *functional* index:

```
CREATE INDEX func_idx__geog__roadstable
  ON roadstable
  USING GIST( (ST_SetSRID(ST_FlipCoordinates(shape), 4326))::GEOGRAPHY )
;
```

should make this a lot faster.